# How to send Objects outside the run method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to be able to use my `sendMessage()` method to send something to my client while also waiting for client messages at the same time (the client should be able to do the same). I tried to define the Socket and Streamobjects everywhere but I think I don't really understand how they work.

```
    public class Server extends Thread{
private ObjectOutputStream oos;

public void sendMessage(String message){
    try
    {
        oos.writeObject(message);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




public void run() {
    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4444);
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        this.oos = oos;
        while(true) {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Server Received: " + message);
            ois.close();
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Server s =  new Server();
   s.start();
   new Client().start();
   s.sendMessage("test");

}
```

**EDIT**

Ok i tried to create a thread for each client but I still have the problem that I can't access the objectoutputstream...

```
public class SuperServer {
    private Server s = new Server();

    public void startServer(){
        s.setDaemon(true);
        s.start();

        if(s.isAlive()){
            System.out.println("server started");
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException
    {
        s.handler.sendMessage(message);
    }
}

public class Server extends Thread {
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket socket;


    ServerHandler handler;



    public void run()
    {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(4444);


            while (true)
            {
                socket = server.accept();
                ServerHandler serverHandler = new ServerHandler(socket);
                handler = serverHandler;

            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }        
}

public class ServerHandler extends Thread {

    protected Socket socket;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;

    public ServerHandler(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException
    {
        oos.writeObject(message);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try(
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4444);
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        )
        {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.oos = oos;
            while (true)
            {
                String message = (String) ois.readObject();
                System.out.println("Server Received: " + message);
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

public class Main {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
       SuperServer s = new SuperServer();
       s.startServer();

       SuperClient c = new SuperClient();
       c.clientStart();

       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("input 1:");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        if(a == 1) s.sendMessage("test");


    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit the question to add the full code of your new try. It makes the post hard to read, so less helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You use incorrectly Thread and Socket.

1) In the server side, generally you want to create a new Thread for each new connection with a client to parallelize the communication between the server and its clients.
Here you create a Thread for the whole server processing...

2)That creates another issue because `Threads.start()` doesn't make run necessarily right now the thread.   So here :

```
Server s =  new Server();
s.start();
new Client().start();
s.sendMessage("test");
```

The  `s.sendMessage("test");` may be invoked before `Server` and `Client` Threads are executed and terminated.  So the `ObjectOutputStream` field could be still `null`.

3) You close the ServerSocket once a first message is read.
So even if    `s.sendMessage("test");` was invoked at the right time (by luck), `ois` will be not `null` but closed this time.

So in summarize :

- perform events at the correct time.
- create new Threads only when required. These are not details.
- don't close sockets if you want still to send/receive messages.

Comment: I tryed to make sure that each client gets its own serverthread but I still have the problem that I cant access the objectoutputstream out of a method. I edited my main post.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't access". What is the error message ?